# Find Visual Studio version with MFC

Tags: visual-studio, mfc, ide

Is there a Visual Studio express version (free) with MFC included ?

Comment: If you are a student, or if you work at a startup that is developing a software product as its core business, you may qualify for free versions of Visual Studio that include MFC. See http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/8055/can-a-developer-get-volume-discount-for-microsoft-products/8059#8059 for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't think so. Sorry. I had to get the premium version when I needed MFC. Let's hope they Microsoft includes MFC in the free version of the next release.

Answer (score 3):

There are no Express editions that come with MFC. You need at least Standard or above.